# What changes needs to be made so the output of a.b.c() is "I should be 'this'"

Tags: javascript

```
var a = {"b": {"c": function() {console.log( this );}}};
var x = {"b": "I should be 'this'"};

a.b.c();
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Vucko, about your edit, that semicolon is not mandatory, but it's not wrong, so I think it should be left in the post.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

Comment: @Vucko it's the second semicolon, not the first. That line is missing a `}`

Answer (score 4):

You could bind the property or take the property as this object.

Without converting to string, you get an array like object in this console.

Methods:

- [Function#bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

  > The **`bind()`** method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.
- [Function#call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

  > The **`call()`** method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually.

Mabe you have a look here, too: [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

```js
var a = { b: { c: function() { console.log(this.toString()); } } },
    x = { b: "I should be 'this'"};

a.b.c.bind(x.b)();
a.b.c.call(x.b);
```